# Как сделать C#-скриптинг для игрового движка, по-типу Unity, только не с Mono/.Net Framework, а с .NET?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, mono

Как сделать C#-скриптинг для игрового движка, по-типу Unity, только не с
Mono/.Net Framework, а с .NET?

Я делаю игровой движок на C++ и хочу добавить в него скриптинг на C#. Не знаю как это можно сделать, ведь я хочу чтобы это работало на .Net, а не на Mono/.Net Framework.

Я новичок в C++, по-этому не знаю, что мне делать (:

Comment: Начать с изучения языка C++CLI .

Comment: Продолжить с C# Interop+Маршаллинг. Но я бы сразу на C# весь движок писал, раз уж сильно хочется. Это было бы полезно для производительности.